# Montecarlo simulation for forecasting loan portfolio growth

Tags: forecasting, montecarlo, deterministic

I have to forecast the future gold loan portfolio growth of a financial firm. I have past 36 month growth. I am planning to use montecarlo simulation to forecast but growth is a deterministic process not a random process. How can I apply montecarlo for this situation?

Please help me friends. Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Your question demonstrates a lack of understanding of the material, I suggest you read a book about Finance and about Monte Carlo simulations before formulating a more specific question.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend. I am going to read about Monte Carlo.